# getting reference of this in jquery ajax handler

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle and refresh content of div based on return code of jquery ajax request.

I believe I am NOT able to tie "item" properly with the ajax request handlers. How can I get reference to "this" inside "success" handler?

I think its because success handle is executed async and the "item" variable is in zombie state.

> - I have two divs starting with add on it
> - When I click add on any div, it fires the ajax req, server handles it and returns success/error
> - Upon success, I toggle add to remove on the div
> - Same toggle happens if I click on remove
> - After few clicks on both divs, I observe my ajax requests are fired 3 -4 times for a single click on either add/remove

I think the way I am adding div in to "item" maybe the issue. I dont know what is wrong. I am thinking of how to write a jsfiddle for this.

I am able to write a jsFiddle and reproduce the prolem. I have mentioned use case above for what my desired behavior is. jsfiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/nEMvD/14/
```

JS:

```
function handleAdd() {
$(".add").click(function(e) {
    var item = $(this).parents(".item")
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html',
        success: function(data) {
          item.find(".add").remove()
          item.append("<div class='remove'>x</div>")
          item.hide().show();
          handleRemove()
        }
    })
});
}
function handleRemove() { 
$(".remove").click(function(e) {
    var item = $(this).parents(".item")
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html',
        success: function(data) {
          item.find(".remove").remove()
          item.append("<div class='add'>+</div>")
          item.hide().show();
           handleAdd()
        }
    })
});
}

$(function() {
  handleAdd()
  handleRemove()
})
```

EDIT:

I think I solved the problem by adding context:this in ajax requests and then using this in handlers. But I will wait for any other better alternative from the community.

Comment: You _can_ refer to your item variable inside the success callback - that's pretty normal. Why do you say you can't do it that way?

Comment: check in browser console if you see error you will know what's wrong. you indeed have JS errors. copy your code in jsfiddle.net and tidyup you will see it.

Comment: i still see more than 4 syntax errors in your code

Comment: see a sample html structure... http://jsfiddle.net/nEMvD/1/

Answer (score 1):

You had errors in your JS code syntax,here is the correct one :

```
 $(".remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = $(this).parents(".item");
    var itemName = item.find(".itemName").text();
    $.ajax({
      url : "/ajax/removeItem/" + itemName,
      dataType : "text",
      success : function(data) {
        item.find(".remove").remove();
        item.append(
          "<div class='add'>" +
             "<span class='addHint'>some text</span>" +
          "</div>"
        );
        item.hide().show();
      }
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: he has problems in syntax , he forgots commas and also problems with   }); i have just edited code it's not an answer